# bIank page codeigniter(locaIhost ok,web n0t)

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, codeigniter

In localhost I can make the install, but in web not. When I try to open the main path it shows a **Blank Page** ,looks like wherever have a htaccess or index.php in web cause problems. I have tried in different servers (+cpanel).
Here is the **.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The codeigniter soft version :  **PHP 5.6, MySQL 5.x**

Comment: blank page means error.Check your error log where is the error.

Comment: I enabled error log and there isn't anything.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you try is to run the controller using index.php in the url.

If you do a view source on your blank page, does it show any HTML at all... Have you examined your default controller and checked it for errors, missing views etc.

If you have developed on Windows and not followed the rules in regards to the naming of your Controllers and Models where they must be 1st letter uppercase.
i.e a controller called home.php must be named Home.php.

Have you renamed your $config['base_url'] to match the domain name...

You need to check these, and there will be others. But as yourself this... If it works on my localhost and not on the hosted website, what is different?

And the above are just some I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: Controllers and Models are just fine ,I have change the URL too.I was thinking if php version made this but after I checked it was all ok.I think the problem is at index.php but I don't know what to change there .
**Here is my index.php : http://choccos.com/my_code/index.txt**
 **Here is my config.php :  http://choccos.com/my_code/config.txt**

Comment: ok, so what if you hardcode your $config['base_url']. What you have there may not be getting correctly set. There is no real need to have it dynamic.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that you put in a blank index.html as your document root is accessible. Once you get this working you could put an index.php that redirects to your site folder... or use htaccess.

Comment: Test index.html : http://choccos.com/site/index.html .
Here is the htaccess file : http://choccos.com/my_code/htaccess.txt